# SharePoint 2010 Global Navigation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, navigation

I have a drop-down menu for Global Navigation in SharePoint Foundation 2010. It is built off of a List. The list contains a column for URL, and I'm having an issue where the domain name is being stripped off of the url. For instance, one of the links is to Lawson, our HR portal. The url is:

```
http://lawsonprodweb.ad.mycompany.com/lawson/portal/index.htm
```

However, when the drop-down menu is built, the URL ends up as:

```
http://lawsonprodweb/lawson/portal/index.htm
```

This doesn't happen if I add the same URL as a quick link. Is there a configuration setting or something I need to change to keep SharePoint from stripping off the domain?